# Filesystem full but empty after corruption

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, data-recovery, fsck

I have a drive of 17 (18TB) which I know had a lot of files on it.

After corruption, i did a fsck on seid drive.

Now, when using df -h the result is the following:

`/dev/sdk         17T  7.5T  8.1T  49% /mnt/drive5`
however, when I cd into the drive, the drive is empty. No files on it. Just the lost+found folder.

```
user@hostname:~$ cd /mnt/drive5
user@hostname:/mnt/drive5$ ls
lost+found
```

going into that folder as root, this folder is empty

trying to do a fsck again, It says the drive is clean..

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/disk/by-uuid/e5d4ea17-a48d-4d8e-9bbb-5d50504aa49a
[sudo] password for user:
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/e5d4ea17-a48d-4d8e-9bbb-5d50504aa49a: clean, 11/274661376 files, 2025315608/4394582016 blocks
user@hostname:~$
```

Is there anyway to restore the file system?

Edit:
Filesystem is ext4

Comment: Which file system is it supposed to have?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of the terminal. Copy the text from the terminal and paste it directly into your question. Then format the pasted lines as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Comment: @ChanganAuto filesystem is supposed to be ext4.

Comment: @user68186 thank you for the hint, replaced the pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use "TestDisk" to recover the filesystem. If that fails you can still try to recover some data using "photorec".
It is considered good practice to work on a copy of the whole partition, because you can break things more while trying to repair. Might be impractical with a large partition though.

Edit: You say you use "ls" to check if there is anyting on the drive, try "la" or "ls -a" to be sure you dont miss any hidden files or folders when trying to figure out what takes up your disk space...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `baobab` to see what's taking up space on the filesystem.

If that doesn't give you a clue, try `gparted`

Comment: Please explain how `gparted` can help recovering lost files +

Comment: I should have added my reasoning for gparted; gparted is to **verify** nothing strange is going on with the partition tables.  While extremely unlikely,  there may be a discrepancy between the partition table and the filesystem size.